# LLVM IR OOP inheritance implementation through C++ API

Tags: c++, inheritance, llvm

so I'm trying to write down a compiler for an *OOP* language with a syntax very similar to *Java*, and I'm stuck at figuring out how inheritance could be implemented.

What I've tried out already is writing a rather basic *C++* inheritance example and compiling it with `clang -S ${FILES} -emit-llvm`.

The C++ code is the following :

**a.hpp:**

```
class A {

    protected:
        int a;

};
```

**b.hpp:**

```
#include "a.hpp"

class B : public A {

    private:
        int b;

    public:
        explicit B();

};
```

**b.cpp:**

```
#include "b.hpp"

B::B() : A() {}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "b.hpp"

int main() {

    B b;

}
```

But I honestly find the output to be really confusing indeed...

What I've discovered Googling is that in order to handle virtual methods and overrides I'll have to use **vtables** (and about that, knowing that I already found [this](https://llvm.org/docs/TypeMetadata.html) tutorial in the `LLVM` doc but I didn't find it really helpful, is there a standard way of creating **vtables** in LLVM)?

I also have quite some doubts about the compilation order...

Let's say I have this source code :

```
package test;
class Test extends SuperTest {}
```

Seems pretty clear to me that in order to merge logical and data structures of `Test` and `SuperTest` while analyzing `Test`, `SuperTest` must have been compiled already, but how do I arrange the compilation such that problems like this cannot arise?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You're on the right track. Compilers are hard. There isn't any standard LLVM way. I am sure a lot of compilers do it broadly the same way though: Create a StructType for the vtable and one for the object early, compute the appropriate content as the source is processed, and then call setBody() late, when the whole content has been parsed. Good luck. This is hard work.